# AngularJS - can't detect event on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making my first steps with angular, I just want to simply clear the content of a input text when I click on it. this is the markup

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input id="123" type="text" ng-click="unsetValue($e)" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input id="456" type="text" ng-click="unsetValue($e)" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```

this is the js in an external file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.firstName= "John";
$scope.lastName= "Doe";

$scope.unsetValue = function($event) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

when I click the control, $event is undefined, any idea why?

thanks
M

Comment: Note the correct syntax in the other post `$event` instead of `$e` and the answer on the linked post shows the directive source which shows the named `$event`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `ng-click` in this way: `ng-click="unsetValue($event)"`

**Update**

Later in the function you can name parameter as you like for example:

```
$scope.unsetValue = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was just a name for a variable, not that I had to use a specific name. I will accept this in 7 mins

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable passed in is `$event`, not `$e`

so you need to use `ng-click` like this

```
ng-click="unsetValue($event)"
```

the rest of your code is fine.